# hidesBarsOnTap - Navigation Bar hidden/displayed event?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I would like to set the background color of a view to black when the navigation bar is hidden, and to white when the navigation bar is displayed.

The property `hidesBarsOnTap` is set to `true` in `viewDidLoad`. This works fine:

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

How can I be notified when the bars are hidden and displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I made a mistake. The following code does exactly what you want. If you have a toolbar, you can set it to hide as well.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var hidden = false {
        didSet {
            if let nav = navigationController {
                nav.setNavigationBarHidden(hidden, animated: true)
                nav.setToolbarHidden(hidden, animated: true)

                view.backgroundColor = hidden ? UIColor.blackColor() : UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap:")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    func tap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == .Ended {
            hidden = !hidden
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I know when the bars are hidden or displayed?
For example, when the user taps on the screen the bars are hidden --> I would like to set the background color to black.
When the user taps again on the screen, the bars are displayed --> I would like to set set the background color to white.

Comment: Updated the answer, making it look a bit better.

Comment: I will mark it as answered as soon as I will get the needed 15 pts of reputation :-)

Comment: you need 15 pts to mark an answer as marked? Aren't you confusing it with upvoting? :)

Answer (score 0):

since `hidesBarsOnTap` is of type boolean, we can easily use it to check and use it as option like in below example:

```
var set : Bool = navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap //true or false

    if (set){
        //do what you want when set
    }else{
    //do what you want when it is not set
    }
```